# How can I get intellisense to work when writing javascript tests in truffle?

Tags: truffle, unittesting

Truffle injects a global web3 instance into your tests and also seems to set up some mocha functions in the global scope (contract, describe and it). When I open the test file for a truffle project in vs code I don't get completion for the global web3 instance and I'm not able to jump to the definition of the mocha testing methods.

How can I configure a project so that the IDE is able to provide intellisense for all the elements inside a truffle test?

Comment: Have a look at Hardhat (e.g. https://hardhat.org/guides/truffle-testing.html) and/or Typechain.

Comment: Do you have any solutions for this?